# Can't set String to URLWithString

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsobject, url-scheme

I'm having an issue with a action to a Facebook page.

The `currentVriend` is a `NSObject` Class.

I get the error: `too many arguments to method call expected 1 have 2`

```
-(void)goFB
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/%g",self.currentVriend.fbid];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
}
```

What am I'm doing wrong? 
Maybe make another `String`?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are missing the correct NSString method

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb://profile/%g",self.currentVriend.fbid]];
```